# How to detect change in GPIO input raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

Is there a way to detect to detect change in raspberry pi GPIO without using a infinite loop?

You can detect rise or fall by using this:

```
GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.RISING, callback=my_callback)
```

But you only can set event detector for either falling or rising at a time. Is there any way to do it without checking the input in a infinite loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use threaded callbacks on `event_detect`. As per [raspberry-gpio-python](http://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/), you can make use of something like this.

`GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.RISING, callback=my_callback)`

Where event could be `GPIO.RISING`, `GPIO.FALLING` or `GPIO.BOTH`, `my_callback` is a normal python function which behaves like an ISR which is run in a different thread.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Oops, I missed the `GPIO.BOTH` bit.

Answer (score 1):

This link might be helpful [raspberry-gpio-python](http://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/)
Basically just use callbacks to do whatever you want at the rising or falling edge instead of polling (what you described)

Answer (score 0):

If you get a simple MCP3004 or MCP3008 IC which is a Analog to Digital converter you can do much more with inputs. Here is some sample code to get you started. [More info on ADC's here](https://learn.adafruit.com/send-raspberry-pi-data-to-cosm/connecting-the-cobbler-slash-mcp3008-slash-tmp36) and how to hook them up to your pi

```
import spidev

#this fucntion can be used to find out the ADC value on ADC 0
def readadc_0(adcnum_0):
    if adcnum_0 > 7 or adcnum_0 < 0:
        return -1
    r_0 = spi_0.xfer2([1, 8 + adcnum_0 << 4, 0])
    adcout_0 = ((r_0[1] & 3) << 8) + r_0[2]
    return adcout_0

reading= readadc_0(0))
```

depending on the resolution of your ADC you will have to do some calculations to get the reading into terms of voltage